# select tuples with more than 30 seconds from each other

Tags: postgresql, gaps-and-islands

sorry for my bad formating, I've never used this platform.

I have a table with some timestamps and I want to select the ones which have more than 30 seconds from each other and are consecutive.

It goes like this:

table called 'nova' with only one column as 'tempo'.

| Tempo |
| --- |
| 2021-06-04 13:48:46-03 |
| 2021-06-04 13:48:50-03 |
| 2021-06-04 13:54:06-03 |
| 2021-06-04 13:56:30-03 |
| 2021-06-04 13:56:31-03 |
| 2021-06-04 13:58:57-03 |
| 2021-06-04 13:58:59-03 |
| 2021-06-04 14:01:30-03 |
| 2021-06-04 14:01:35-03 |
| 2021-06-04 14:04:08-03 |
| 2021-06-04 14:06:45-03 |

I want to select the ones that are spaced as least 30 seconds apart.
But whenever I state:

"select distinct t1.* from nova t1, nova t2 where t2.tempo-t1.tempo > '00:00:30';"

Postgres does not filter any entry as it operates all tuples with one another and there is always one combination where the difference is greater than 30 seconds.

I need to filter the consecutive entries, prioritizing the older entries, as follows:

| Tempo |
| --- |
| 2021-06-04 13:48:46-03 |
| 2021-06-04 13:54:06-03 |
| 2021-06-04 13:56:30-03 |
| 2021-06-04 13:58:57-03 |
| 2021-06-04 14:01:30-03 |
| 2021-06-04 14:04:08-03 |
| 2021-06-04 14:06:45-03 |

thanks for your help!

Comment: This is sometimes called a [tag:gaps-and-islands] problem, for your information

Comment: Only regarding consecutive timestamps or just any other timestamp that is 30 seconds apart? Only older ones, only younger ones or both? For clarity [edit] the question and provide a [example], i.e. the `CREATE` statements of the tables or other objects involved (paste the **text**, don't use images, don't link to external sites), `INSERT` statements for sample data (dito) and the desired result with that sample data in tabular text format. And show what you have tried already **explicitly** -- post the code. Explain why/where it failed. Be specific (error message, unexpected result, etc.).

Comment: I will edit and clarify.
I am trying to find the consecutive timestamps spaced not less than 30 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

This query solves that problem:

```
with q as (select tempo, lead(tempo) over (order by tempo) from nova)
select tempo from q where lead is null or age(lead, tempo) > '30 seconds';
```

Comment: That nailed it!
Thanks!